# sed command to avoid update for particular line

Tags: regex, sed

**File content:**
File contains 3 lines as below

```
`ovm_info(get_full_name() ,  " DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_tag", dst.addr, dst.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


`ovm_info("TOP" ,  $sformatf("DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_uma_tag", dst_ag_result.addr, dst_ag_result.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


/* `ovm_info( get_name() ,  "DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d, ",  OVM_MEDIUM)
```

**Requirement:**
To remove the first argument in each line.
First argument can be anything get_name(), get_full_name(), "TOP" , its a random pattern.

**Result should look like**

```
`ovm_info(     ,  "DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_tag", dst.addr, dst.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


`ovm_info(     ,  $sformatf(" DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_uma_tag", dst_ag_result.addr, dst_ag_result.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


/* `ovm_info(     ,  " DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d, ",  OVM_MEDIUM)
```

**Trial Done:**

```
sed -i '/ovm_info/ s/[^\,]*\,/`ovm_info( ,"/'
```

**But the issue with the above command is it will give result as below.
For the 3rd line there is " /* " at the beginning which i am not able to retain**

```
`ovm_info(      ,  " DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_tag", dst.addr, dst.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


`ovm_info(    ,  $sformatf("DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_uma_tag", dst_ag_result.addr, dst_ag_result.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


`ovm_info(    ,  "DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d, ",  OVM_MEDIUM)
```

Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sed -e 's#(.[^,]*#(            #g'
```

Demo:

```
$cat input.txt 
`ovm_info(get_full_name() ,  " DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_tag", dst.addr, dst.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


`ovm_info("TOP" ,  $sformatf("DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_uma_tag", dst_ag_result.addr, dst_ag_result.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


/* `ovm_info( get_name() ,  "DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d, ",  OVM_MEDIUM)

$sed -e 's#(.[^,]*#(            #g' input.txt 
`ovm_info(            ,  " DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_tag", dst.addr, dst.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


`ovm_info(            ,  $sformatf(            , length: %0d", "dma_uma_tag", dst_ag_result.addr, dst_ag_result.length), OVM_MEDIUM)


/* `ovm_info(            ,  "DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d, ",  OVM_MEDIUM)

$
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But now the issue comes in the 2nd line  `ovm_info(    ,  $sformatf("DMA region for %s: base: 0x%x, length: %0d", "dma_uma_tag", dst_ag_result.addr, dst_ag_result.length), OVM_MEDIUM).   the content after $format( , is also getting removed now. but this should not happen.    What ever First argument comes only after "ovm_info" must be removed in the line.

Comment: Got the issue resolved.   sed -e 's#ovm_info(.[^,]*#ovm_info(            #g'